# Web application is very slow until restart iis

Tags: asp.net, debugging, iis

I have some problem in IIS. I install Debug Diagnostic Tool for my problem.

After run it and start Analysis i get 1 error with this message:

In w3wp_*system*_PID_*696*_Date__09_22_2012__Time_11_44_51AM_*967*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at msxml6!Base::freeRentalObjects+75 in C:\Windows\System32\msxml6.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000008 on thread

How can i resolve this?

Comment: I googled it and found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959877  It is behaving as if two threads are trying to read the same document. This can happen if your app and say a virus scanner try to read the same document, or if two identical requests try to use teh same xml file.

Comment: Do you properly close and dispose I/O resources after using them?

Comment: Dennis Traub: I use LinQ to SQL. Should I dispose context after each search from database? I don't dispose context in my operation.